# rmarkdown - embed sparkline into a bootstrap popover

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap-3, r-markdown, sparklines

I'm trying to display a sparkline in a popover. I'm using rmarkdown to create my html document.

Here is my attempt:

````
---
title: "test_embed_popup"
author: "me"
date: "16 June 2017"
output: html_document
---  

```{r}
library(sparkline)
library(htmltools)
library(bsplus)

bsplus::use_bs_popover()

button_content <- 
  spk_chr(c(1:5))

tags$button(type = "button", class = "btn btn-default", "A button") %>%
  bs_embed_popover(title = "I'm a popover", content = button_content, html = "true") %>% 
  sparkline::spk_add_deps()
```
````

when i knit this document, the button with the popover appears however no sparkline is in the popover. I would like to display the sparkline in the popover.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fiddled with this a bit - I think that the underlying problem is that the JavaScript is not being executed. This is discussed here:

[Execute JS inside of a Bootstrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409144/execute-js-inside-of-a-bootstrap-popover)

I think the proposed solution is probably out of scope (at least for now) for bsplus - but I've made an [issue](https://github.com/ijlyttle/bsplus/issues/42) to remind myself.